# Disable new account email notification in WooCommerce

Tags: hook-woocommerce

I need to disable the default email sending of New Account to admin.

I have looked at the unhook_those_pesky_emails code but dont see it for New Accounts

The snippet of code probably start like
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer_notification',`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking in the future, this is likely the code you need:

```
<?php    

//Disable 'new user' notification for the site admin

function woo_disable_new_user_notifications() {
    
 //Remove original emails

 remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
 remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
 
 //Add new function to take over email creation

 add_action( 'register_new_user', 'woo_send_new_user_notifications' );
 add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'woo_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
}
function woo_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify = 'user' ) {
 if ( empty($notify) || $notify == 'admin' ) {
 return;
 }elseif( $notify == 'both' ){
 //Only send the new user an email, not the admin
 $notify = 'user';
 }
 woo_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify );
}
add_action( 'init', 'woo_disable_new_user_notifications' );
```

This will disable WordPress notifications to the site admin regarding new user registrations.